# Implement basic autocomplete in Java

Tags: java, autocomplete, trie

Given an array of words and phrases, given a key, return :

- All words that start with the key
- All phrases that contain a word that start with key

For example:

`wordbank = ["bang", "base", "bore", "band", "This is a baffling problem];`

`key = "ba";`

`autocomplete(wordbank, key)` should return `["bang", "base", "band", "This is a baffling problem]`

I used a Trie to do it, but just wondering if [this is a good solution?](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMODkzSHljY1VOY2M)

To run, just enter `java Test` in the terminal. The test case in the link is not the same as the example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code may be simplified in the following way. Add a set of autocomplete results to each node of the try. When inserting a word in a try, simultaneously add autocomplete set to each visited node. To perform an autocomplete, just return autocomplete set for the corresponding node.

This solution adds one line to `insertWord` and `getWordsWithPrefix`, while completely remove the need of `buildWords`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be significantly worse space complexity though? It would mean saving the same word over and over.

Comment: Nodes will contain only references to the autocomplete string, no the strings itself. And there will be the same number of references to the word, as its length. So the total memory usage will be proportional to the total length of all words, i.e. asymptotically the same as existing solution.